# Literatur for extensions of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I'm searching for books about existence of extensions of functions.
Maybe you have some tips, where I can find results about:

- Conditions for the domain, where my function is defined
- Conditions for the function I want to extend
- Conditions for the boundary of the domain

I'm looking for results of the form:
*For a $C^k$ function on a $C^m$ domain $\Omega$ there exists a $C^l$ extension to...*

Also for functions which are Hölder to an exponent $\alpha$ this would be interesting.

Comment: Try searching for items that make reference to Hassler Whitney, such as [the Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) and the mathoverflow question [A result attributed to Whitney](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196167/a-result-attributed-to-whitney). For the more concrete setting of the real numbers (but with more subtle issues considered), try the google search [differentiable + extension + "Jack B Brown"](https://www.google.com/search?q=differentiable+extension+%22Jack+B+Brown%22).